# Searching for protractor test recorder

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, selenium-rc, recorder

I want to test an Angularjs Project using protractor and I am looking for test recorder (like Selenium IDE) to make it without writing the test cases. Is there any tool available?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Try [protractor recorder](https://github.com/ealves/protractor-recorder). It is a webapp to recorder and run tests with protractor. You can enter a base url, click on 'Record' to start recording mouse and keyboard events. You can also export the conf.js and spec.js and run directly from the interface.

Answer (score 6):

Try [elementor](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor). It is not a recorder, but it will help you find locators for your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building a test-recorder for different test frameworks. 
https://github.com/QuantumInformation/test-recorder